# react+webpack Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' Loading chunk 7 failed

Tags: reactjs, webpack

after executing below command

```
rpm run build
```

I upload file to nginx-server
page seems normal, but every button that can jump to the Secondary page throws error.

[image: error]

normal sources：

[image: normal sources]

The following configuration has been set up，still not work...
[image: configuration]

[image]

Comment: Hello @Palak, did you later find a solution to this?

Comment: @codebarz HI, did you later find a solution to this?

Comment: I used a service worker to cache the current bundle so the app doesn't crash when this error occurs and then automatically update the worker if there is any change